# How to configure pylint in visual studio code to search project directories for modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

In visual studio code I am getting the error:

> [pylint] unable to import from Controllers.InterferenceGraph

The line of code is

```
from Controllers.InterferenceGraph import InterferenceGraph
```

The file `InterferenceGraph.py` is in the same directory as the line with the error. how do I configure pylint to look in the current directory or mutiple directories to look in?

Comment: You mean `InterferenceGraph` is defined inside `InterferenceGraph.py` file and `InterferenceGraph.py` is in same directory as the current file?

Comment: If so, then why not do `from InterferenceGraph import InterferenceGraph`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pylint, you can tell pylint where to look for imports. You need to create a `.pylintrc` file if you already don't have in your home directory. And add the following lines:

```
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("/path/to/repo")'
```

where `/path/to/repo` is the absolute path of the directory where the file is kept.